# Есть ли в Laravel RBAC?

Tags: php, laravel

Есть ли адекватные реализации RBAC для Laravel? То, что я встречал на GitHub было индусской поделкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пользуюсь вот этим , проблем не испытывал

https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust

Comment: Спасибо. Это раньше не встречал.

Answer (score 1):

Сделал [аналог](https://github.com/yiisoft/rbac) для *Laravel* с наследованием прав и ролей + правила срабатывания для условных допусков.

[Документация](https://github.com/centeron/laravel-roles-permissions) на русском имеется.

Answer (score 0):

Позволяет задать и проверить права на конкретную запись:
https://github.com/SmartCrowd/laravel-rbac

Пример:

```
if (Auth::user()->allowed('article.delete', ['article' => $article])) {
    // user has access to 'somePermission.name' permission
}
```

Вариант RBAC с наследованием ролей:
https://github.com/DynamicCodeNinja/RBAC

Answer (score 0):

В Laravel нет RBAC из коробки, но есть Gate и Policy, которые могут помочь реализовать RBAC.

Сам пользуюсь [visualappeal/laravel-rbac](https://packagist.org/packages/visualappeal/laravel-rbac)

Работает отлично.

Comment: Вы повысите качество ответа , если добавите сокращённое содержание ссылки прямо в тело ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Есть замечательный RBAC пакет https://github.com/itstructure/laravel-rbac